# EF6 throws Specified cast is not valid on async method

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

When using `await` and `FirstOrDefaultAsync` I get **Specified cast is not valid** exception.

```
var a = Db.Table1.SqlQuery("select * from Table1 where rownum =1 ").FirstOrDefault();
var b = await Db.Table1.SqlQuery("select * from Table1 where rownum =1 ").FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

so a is fine b throws error. What am I missing?

```
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataReader.GetFieldValue[T](Int32 ordinal)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataReader.GetFieldValueAsync[T](Int32 ordinal, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ShapedBufferedDataRecord.<ReadIntAsync>d__25.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.TaskExtensions.CultureAwaiter.GetResult()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ShapedBufferedDataRecord.<InitializeAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.BufferedDataReader.<InitializeAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<ExecuteStoreQueryInternalAsync>d__73`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.TaskExtensions.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<ExecuteInTransactionAsync>d__3d`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.TaskExtensions.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbExecutionStrategy.<ProtectedExecuteAsync>d__9`1.MoveNext()
```

Comment: What is the stack trace on the exception? Presumably the call is within an async method?

Comment: added stack trace, seems like error casting Int32 but why

Answer (score 0):

I will post an answer in case someone hits this issue. Some properties were missing on the Table1 EF model or in other words the table Table1 had extra fields. Why this wasn't causing FirstOrDefault and only causing errors with FirstOrDefaultAsync I have no idea, may be different implementation. So the solution is to sync Table1 DB table and Table1 EF model